# Where is the current location of Harry Bennett's art used for Herman Wouk's "Lomokome" Papers?

Tags: art

Harry Bennett created the cover art for several novels (https://www.pinterest.com/nowvintage/harry-bennett-book-covers/) including *The "Lomokome" Papers* (https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?157061) by Herman Wouk. Bennett also drew several beautiful drawings for the interior of the 1968 edition of this book. I'd like to see the full-sized versions of these drawings, which were reproduced only in small format in the novel. Does anyone know of a museum, archive, or other repository that holds Bennett's original art or reproductions from this work?

Incidentally, Herman Wouk, who was the author of *The Caine Mutiny* and other mainstream novels, died yesterday (May 17, 2019). So far as I know, *The "Lomokome" Papers* was his only work of science fiction.

Comment: What are you actually asking?

Comment: Has his work been preserved in a museum or archive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several of his works seem to have [come up](https://www.artprice.com/artist/130087/harry-bennett/lots/pasts) [at auction](https://www.mutualart.com/Artist/Harry-R--Bennett/962B1C07C4FDD1B0/AuctionResults), but not in any significant numbers, nor generating any significant prices. Similarly, he [exhibited at his local library](http://riverseagallery.squarespace.com/artists-2d/harry-bennett/), but these were one-off creations and commissions.

It would appear that his family are holding the majority of his works at their homes.

> JKP: Finally, do you have any of your father’s art in your home?
>
> TB: Yes, I have quite a few of his paintings and drawings. My siblings do as well. We also all share a number of [examples of] his book-cover art, many on canvas, mostly on gessoed board.
>
> <sub><sup>[Bennett’s Beauties: A Father’s Legacy](http://killercoversoftheweek.blogspot.com/2018/03/bennetts-beauties-fathers-legacy.html)</sup></sub>

Comment: Thank you for "going the extra mile" to research this.

Comment: @InvisibleTrihedron - No worries. His son seems quite amenable. If you want to buy that specific piece of artwork, you might want to chuck him an email; https://www.flickr.com/photos/tom-bennett/

Comment: Thank you again. I don't know what will come of it, but I'll take the opportunity to tell him that I appreciated his father's art.